# Prove that $\underline{\int_{a}^b} f \leq 0 \leq \overline{\int_{a}^{b} f}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My question is just to make sure my proof is on the right track.

Problem: Suppose that the bounded function $f\colon [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that for each $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, where $a\leq x\leq b$, $f\left(x\right)=0$. Prove that

$$\underline{\int_{a}^b} f \leq 0 \leq \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f.$$

I am going to show the part $\underline{\int_{a}^b} f \leq 0$, because the other part should be similar.

Proof:

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ means that there is $x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$, where $f\left(x\right)=0$. Furthermore, since $$m_i\equiv \text{inf}\left\{f\left(x\right) | \; x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\right\}$$ means $m_i \leq 0 \: \text{for} \: i \geq 1$.

$$\implies L\left(f, P\right)= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right) \leq 0,$$ where $P$ is a partition of $[a, b]$.

Furthermore, since $$\underline{\int_{a}^b} f \equiv \: \text{sup}\left\{L\left(f, P\right)\right\},$$

$$\implies \underline{\int_{a}^b} f \leq 0.$$

Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: is $f$ continuous ?

Comment: The only stipulation is that $f$ is bounded. The problem is stated word for word.

Comment: actually, $\int_{-a}^b f$ is not define a priori if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb  R$

Comment: Are we meant to assume that f is Reimann integrable? Certainly it must be integrable if the integral is to be defined, but a counterexample Lebesgue integrable function is easy to find.

Comment: Yes, this is in the section for Darboux sums and integrals (6.1) problem 3 in Fitzpatrick's Advanded Calculus.

Comment: I am still not sure the problem statement is correct. Consider $a=1$, $b=2$, $f(x)=1$ for $x<a$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge a$. Then $\int_{-1}^2 f(x)dx = 2$.

Comment: The question is word for word out of the book as follows: Suppose that the bounded function $f\colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that for each rational number $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$, $f\left(x\right)=0$. Prove that $\int_{-a}^b f \leq 0 \leq \int_{a}^{-b} f$.

Comment: Note that $\int_{-a}^b$ is defined as sup$\left\{L\left(f,P\right)| P \: \text{is a partition of} \: [a, b]\right\}$.

Comment: I assume you meant lower and upper integrals, so I fixed LaTeX accordingly. If that's not what you meant, feel free to change it back.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, I just did not know how to format it that way.